# Lock error in sql server after updating and selecting

Tags: sql, sql-server, locking, sql-server-2012, deadlock

In my code, i need to assign the Pallet number to the selected carton boxes.

once the user the selects the boxes(15-30 boxes) and press OK, i run the following code.

```
//UPDATE THE PALLET NO FOR ALL THE SELECTED CARTONS

          foreach (DataGridViewRow item in dgvCartonDetails.Rows)
            {
                dbLayer.tblCartonUpdatePalletid(item.Cells["CM_ID"].Value.ToString(), Pno, _Settings.Line.ToString());

    //STORED PROCEDURE:tblCartonUpdatePalletid
    //update tblCarton set CM_palletid = @palletid, cm_cartoncompletetime = getdate() where cm_id = @cm_id
            }
            //PRINT ALL THE BOXES IN THE PALLET
            dbLayer.tblPrintAllCartonsOfthePallet(PalletID);

    //STORED PROCEDURE: tblPrintAllCartonsOfthePallet
    //select * from tblCarton where cm_palletid = @PalletID
```

Some times i face the lock error (ref pic).

[image]

I have given the stored procedure data as well for referance. Carton table will increase at the rate of 5000 records/day.

I dont know what i am missing. where should i look into? Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1):

There must be another process running at the same time. You need to identify what it is. The best thing to do if possible is to capture a deadlock in profiler as it will show you exactly which processes deadlocked and one which resource.

I assume you run those 2 queries in 1 transaction.

If there are 2 processes running the code above, what may happen is they update `tblCarton` at the same time. The first one updates a record on page 1 and the second updates a record on page 2. Then they need to update the pages in reverse: first needs to update page 2 and second page 1. That will result in a deadlock.

Without getting a deadlock report from profiler, it's hard to say if this is happening for sure, though.